# Diferenças entre Jagged Array e Multidimensional Array em c#?

Tags: c#, array

Existe diferença nesses arrays em c#?

`int[][][]`

`int[,,]`

Pelo que eu vejo é a mesma coisa, mas o c# não consegue fazer cast de um para o outro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O *cast* não é possível porque `int[][][]` e `int[,,,]` declaram [*arrays*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) diferentes.

`int[][][]` é um *array* de *arrays* de *arrays*([*Jagged array*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)). Cada elemento do primeiro *array* é um *array* que por sua vez tem por elementos um *array*. Cada um dos *array* podem ter dimensões diferentes.

`int[,,,]` é um *array* com três dimensões([*Multidimensional Array*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)), cada elemento é um `int`. Cada linha terá sempre o mesmo número de colunas.

É até possível misturar os dois:

```
int[][,,][,]
```

O código anterior declara um *array* unidimensional([*Single-Dimensional Array*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0.aspx)) de *arrays* tridimensionais de *arrays* bidimensionais do tipo `int`.

A notação `[]` indica que o objecto é um *array*, as virgulas indicam o número de dimensões do array.

Answer (score 8):

A [Jagged Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2s05feca.aspx)  é uma Matriz de Matrizes, um `int[][]` é uma matriz de `int[]`. Os elementos podem conter tamanhos e dimensões diferentes.

*Exemplo:*

```
int [][] jagged = new int [3][];
jagged [0] = new int [2]{1,2};
jagged [1] = new int [6]{3,4,5,6,7,8};
jagged [2] = new int [3]{9,10,11};
```

*Ilustração do código acima:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já o [Multidimensional Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) `(int[,])` é uma unico bloco de memoria (matriz em si). Mais coesa se parecendo com uma caixa, quadrado, etc em que não há colunas irregulares.

*Exemplo:*

Array bidimensional de três linhas por três colunas.

```
int [,] multidimensional  = new int[3, 3] {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
```

Ilustração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resposta adapatada de: [FONTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimentional-array)