# É possível fazer um array de arrays?

Tags: c#, array

Em um datagridview de 3 colunas preciso varrer todas as n linhas e salvar todas elas em um array (ou em uma coleção qualquer) onde cada índice contém as informações de cada linha do datagrid. Algo do tipo:

meuArray[linha1, linha2, linha3, linha4,...]

Onde cada linha é armazenada em um outro array:

linha1[celulaColuna0, celulaColuna1, celulaColuna2]

Existe algum meio de fazer isso?

Comment: Sim, isto se chama [*multidimensional array*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145897/101), embora pareça pelo texto que quer *jagged array*, está com algum problema? Se for só isso acho que é duplicata, se for mais que isto, não está claro que precisa melhorar a pergunta. Dá para reabrir se a pergunta for outra, mas precisaria melhorar bastante com um problema específico.

Comment: Isso que vc pediu (array de array), como o @bigown disse, são Jagged Arrays. Mas pra tabelas o array multidimensional costuma ser melhor, pois em princípio uma tabela é uma massa única de dados distribuida em dois eixos. Veja a diferença na pergunta indicada.

Comment: Certo! Obrigado, bigown e Bacco.
Bacco, mas um array de array no meu caso seria mais fácil de manipular depois.

Comment: @Vinícius realmente as especificidades só dependem do seu caso real. Entendo que se for recuperar a linha para mandar em separado para algum outro método ou função, a jagged pode ser interessante, apesar do custo um pouco maior (o que é desprezível se não for um volume gigantesco de dados).

Comment: @Bacco, sim! Serão no máximo 10 linhas. Muito obrigado!!!