# Acessar informação em array Associativo Multidimensional (PHP)?

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho o seguinte estrutura:

```
$arrDados = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [NumeroEmpenhoNumero] => Array ( 
            [type] => NULL 
            [size] => 0 
            [deci] => 0 
            [code] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [NumeroEmpenhoAno] => Array ( 
            [type] => NULL 
            [size] => 0 
            [deci] => 0 
            [code] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [UnidadeOrcamentaria] => Array ( 
            [type] => NULL 
            [size] => 0 
            [deci] => 0 
            [code] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [UnidadeExecutora] => Array ( 
            [type] => NULL 
            [size] => 0 
            [deci] => 0 
            [code] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [Historico] => Array ( 
            [type] => NULL 
            [size] => 0 
            [deci] => 0 
            [code] => 0 
        ) 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [OperacaoCadastro] => Array ( 
            [type] => NULL 
            [size] => 0 
            [deci] => 0 
            [code] => 0
        ) 
    )
);
```

Preciso acessar algo **como**:

```
$arrDados['NumeroEmpenhoNumero']['code']
```

**ou**

```
$arrDados['NumeroEmpenhoNumero']['size']
```

mas fica dando **erro**:

> Undefined offset: 'NumeroEmpenhoNumero' in ...on line 222

- Como consigo acessar essas posições deste array?
- Qual a sintaxe correta?

Comment: Só uma observação, o PHP não tem Array multidimensional. Tem é Array de Array. O uso é parecido, mas é uma estrutura totalmente diferente internamente. Em C#, por exemplo, temos dos 2 tipos: [Diferenças entre Jagged Array e Multidimensional Array em c#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145897/70)

Answer (score 2):

Você está se esquecendo do index do array, você pode acessar da seguinte maneira:

```
echo  $arrDados[0]["NumeroEmpenhoNumero"]["size"]; // Acessando de forma fixa


foreach ($arrDados as $key => $value) { 
   foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
      echo $v["size"]; //Acessando de forma dinâmica

   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.