# Qual a diferença entre array e matriz?

Tags: array, terminologia, matriz

Depois de ver *arrays* e matrizes em programação, fiquei um pouco confuso, então gostaria de saber, qual a diferença entre um *array* e uma *matriz*?

Comment: []..."Existe o vetor de vetores que muitas vezes é confundido com matriz, mas não é, afinal os tamanhos de cada linha ou coluna é variável, uma matriz mantém tudo do mesmo tamanho, mantendo o "desenho retangular"." Por definição, array/vetor tem um tamanho fixo

Answer (score 26):

Isso é mais um conceito matemático do que de programação.

Assim como um quadrado é um caso particular de um quadrilátero, um *array* é um caso particular de uma matriz: é uma matriz apenas com uma dimensão.
Entenda-se aqui *array* como sinónimo de vector.

Em programação o tipo *Array* é uma estrutura de dados cujos elementos podem ser manipulados/acedidos através de índices e pode ter uma ou mais dimensões.

Os termos vector e matriz, por analogia à matemática, são por vezes usados para denominar *Arrays* unidimensionais e *Arrays* bidimensionais, respectivamente.

Answer (score 19):

Há algumas controvérsias sobre isto, mas vou dizer o que é mais aceito.

[*Array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101) é o nome inglês para o que chamamos de [vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124849/101).

Um vetor é uma matriz de uma dimensão só, ou seja, tem apenas uma linha ou uma coluna de dados. Normalmente usamos o termo matriz quando há mais de uma dimensão, então tem pelo menos linhas e colunas, pode ter outras dimensões.

Em outras palavras matriz é um vetor multidimensional.

Existe o [vetor de vetores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145897/101) que muitas vezes é confundido com matriz, mas não é, afinal os tamanhos de cada linha ou coluna é variável, uma matriz mantém tudo do mesmo tamanho, mantendo o "desenho retangular".

- [Definição matemática de *array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array).
- [Definição computacional de *array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure).
- [Definição matemática de matriz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Em outras palavras matriz é um vetor multidimensional."---exemplo: (1,1,1) multidimensional ------

Um vetor multidimensional ainda é só um vetor, mas que se apresenta em várias dimensões. Para mim uma matriz nada mais é do que um vetor de vetores onde esses têm o mesmo tamanho, e esse ultimo se escala como quiser mantendo sempre o tamanho igual . Entende se esse vetor dentro do primeiro vetor pode ser também um vetor de vetores, formando uma matriz de dimensão 3.

Comment: Conforme eu escrevi um vetor de vetor não é uma matriz, tem *link* mostrando a diferença.

Comment: exemplo: (1,1,1) multidimensional  que não é uma matriz

Comment: Em programação de computadores, um arranjo (em inglês array) é uma estrutura de dados que armazena uma coleção de elementos de tal forma que cada um dos elementos possa ser identificado por, pelo menos, um índice ou uma chave. Essa estrutura de dados também é conhecida como variável indexada, vetor (para arranjos unidimensionais) e matriz (para arranjos bidimensionais)

Comment: A tradução de array pra vetor ainda não é a melhor. Seria propriamente Arranjo

Comment: Não tem nada de multi dimensional nisso, só tem uma dimensão. Agora, conforme eu disse no início, há controvérsias, tem definições diferentes, em computação a mais aceita é essa que eu disse, o que bate inclusive com a resposta do ramaral. Eu não gosto tanto dessa definição da Wikipedia, afinal 3 dimensões também é uma matriz. Todo mundo usa vetor, a melhor tradução é o que todo mundo usa, mesmo que estritamente ela não seja a mais adequada. Mas isso é outra discussão.

Comment: leia-se x=1, y=1, z=1 => vetor multidimensional. Meio inútil discutir aqui... deixarei assim, e não renderei mais

Comment: @UmProgramador Em parte concordo consigo: em inglês array não é um vector. No entanto também concordo com o bigown: é comummente usado array como sinónimo de vector. Repare que, na minha resposta, tive o cuidado de dizer "Entenda-se aqui array como sinónimo de vector" e de acrescentar **tipo**, quando me referi ao array no domínio da programação. Assim, pelo entendimento que tenho da palavra inglesa *array*, uma matriz é um caso particular de array e não o contrário. Mas como o bigown diz "a melhor tradução é o que todo mundo usa"

Comment: "a melhor tradução é o que todo mundo usa" afirma que se todo mundo ta errado o errado é o certo. O que não é verdade. A melhor tradução é aquela mais próxima do verdadeiro significado

Comment: Esse assunto é de linguística, isso deve ser discutido em https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/, lá tem especialista nisso, aqui discutimos computação, falamos de terminologia na forma como usamos, certo ou errado do ponto de vista linguístico.