# Ordenar uma matriz em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando ordenar uma matriz em C. A lógica que eu usei seria criar um vetor com o tamanho da matriz, copiar os valores para lá, ordenar os valores e depois copiar para a matriz novamente. Para fazer isso eu uso uma função que recebe como parâmetros as dimensões da matriz e o seu endereço (manipulação através de ponteiros). Porém quando eu vou fazer a cópia para o vetor, os valores armazenados são outros totalmente diferente.

```
int ordenaMatriz(int **matriz, int lin, int col){

int i, j, menor, cont=0, indice;
int vetor[lin*col]; 

for(i=0;i<lin;i++){
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        vetor[cont]=matriz[i][j];
        cont++;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<(lin*col);i++){
    printf("%d ", vetor[cont]);
}
for(i=0;i<lin*col;i++){
    menor=vetor[i];
    for(j=0;j<lin*col;j++){
        if(vetor[j]<menor){
            menor=vetor[j];
            int aux = vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = menor;
            vetor[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<lin;i++){
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        matriz[i][j]=vetor[cont];
        cont++;
    }
}

}
```

Main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int lin, col, i;
int **matriz;

printf("Digite as dimensoes da matriz: ");
scanf("%d %d", &lin, &col);

alocaMatriz(&matriz, lin, col);
leMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
mostraMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
ordenaMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
printf("\n\nMatriz ordenada:\n\n");
mostraMatriz(matriz, lin, col);
desalocaMatriz(&*matriz, lin, col);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Veja isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232895/101. Pra que tanta cópia? é possível fazer sem cópia alguma. Fica um pouco mais fácil fazendo uma cópia, mas tantas não sei porque. Term dificuldades que surgem porque o algoritmo está muito complexo. De qualquer forma acho que falta informações para podermos ajudar. Basicamente está dizendo que tem um erro e a gente que se vire para achar. Tem erros de sintaxe neste código.

Comment: Verifique o que significa matriz[i][j] quando você colocou como **matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função de ordenação está com dois problemas.

Um é meramente visual, a parte em que imprime a copia antes de ordenar:

```
for(i=0;i<(lin*col);i++){
    printf("%d ", vetor[cont]);
}
```

Repare que está a mostrar `vetor[cont]` em vez de `vetor[i]`, sendo que `i` é a variável do `for`. Mas este problema é apenas na impressão não afeta a ordenação em si.

Depois na recolocação dos valores na matriz original faltou-lhe iniciar o `cont` a `0` de novo:

```
for(i=0, cont = 0 /*<= faltava este*/; i<lin; i++ /*O cont++ também podia ficar aqui*/)
{
    for(j=0; j<col; j++)
    {
        matriz[i][j]=vetor[cont];
        cont++;
    }
}
```

Isto já lhe dá o resultado que espera

[Que pode ver no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eU2AND)

Também dava para ordenar sem criar o vetor auxiliar mas iria tornar o código mais complexo, necessitando de 4 `for` uma vez que cada 2 `for` percorrem a matriz do inicio ao fim.