# Soma dos elementos da diagonal secundária de uma matriz

Tags: java, funções, matriz

Fiz um programa que o usuário declara o tamanho da matriz, e os números da matriz são aleatórias. Porém na parte da soma não funciona e exibe muitos erros.

```
Java
    public  static  void  main ( String[] args ) {
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite o numero de linhas da matriz:\n ");
        int linha = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Digite o numero de colunas da matriz:\n ");
        int coluna = input.nextInt();

        int[][] matriz = new int[linha][coluna];
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
            matriz[linha][coluna] = aleatorio.nextInt(9);
        }
        System.out.printf("%d ", matriz[linha][coluna]);
    
        //Essa parte não funciona
        public static int somaDiagonal(matriz [][]) {
        int soma = 0;
        coluna = matriz.length - 1;
        for (linha = 0; linha < matriz.length; linha++){
           soma += matriz[linha][coluna];
           coluna--;
           }
        return soma;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se foi erro de digitação, mas você criou o método `somaDiagonal` **dentro** do método `main`. Esqueça isso. Ou crie um método fora do `main`, ou não use o método e coloque todo o código no próprio `main`.

Outro detalhe é que o `for` para preencher a matriz está errado. Você está indo da primeira à ultima linha, e sempre setando `matriz[linha][coluna]` (ou seja, está tentando mudar sempre a mesma posição). Outro detalhe é que `linha` é a quantidade de linhas, mas os índices da matriz vão de zero a `linha - 1`, então ao tentar acessar a posição `linha`, dará erro.

Na verdade você tem que fazer dois `for` aninhados (um para as linhas, outro para as colunas) e ir preenchendo cada posição.

Vale lembrar que na verdade não existem matrizes de fato em Java. O que temos são arrays de arrays: um array no qual cada elemento é outro array. A diferença é que cada um desses arrays pode ter um tamanho diferente, e cabe ao programador controlar isso de forma que todos tenham o mesmo tamanho (em uma matriz, todas as linhas obrigatoriamente teriam a mesma quantidade de colunas, [como é feito em C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays), por exemplo - [veja aqui a diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145897/112052)).

Neste caso está bem controlado, então não vou incluir as verificações de tamanho. Mas enfim, para preencher a matriz seria algo assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
        matriz[i][j] = aleatorio.nextInt(9);
        System.out.printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Repare como eu preencho a posição `[i][j]`, pois `i` e `j` variam no *loop* - ou seja, a cada iteração estou preenchdo uma posição diferente (fazendo `[linha][coluna]`, você estava tentando mudar sempre a mesma posição, já que os valores de `linha` e `coluna` não variavam).

---

Já para a diagonal secundária, você tem que começar pelo último elemento da primeira linha, depois o penúltimo da segunda linha, e assim por diante. Mas vale lembrar que se a matriz não for quadrada, você tem que parar quando terminarem as linhas ou colunas. Por exemplo, em uma matriz 2 x 4:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

A diagonal secundária são os números 4 e 7.

Já em uma matriz 4 x 2:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

A diagonal secundária são os números 2 e 3.

Enfim, ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random aleatorio = new Random();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite o numero de linhas da matriz:\n ");
    int linha = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Digite o numero de colunas da matriz:\n ");
    int coluna = input.nextInt();

    int[][] matriz = new int[linha][coluna];
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = aleatorio.nextInt(9);
            System.out.printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Soma da diagonal secundária=" + somaDiagonal(matriz));
}

// crie o método fora do main
public static int somaDiagonal(int[][] matriz) {
    int soma = 0;
    int coluna = matriz[0].length - 1; // último elemento da primeira linha
    for (int linha = 0; linha < matriz.length; linha++) {
        soma += matriz[linha][coluna];
        coluna--;
        if (coluna < 0) // acabaram as colunas, interrompe o for
            break;
    }
    return soma;
}
```

---

Um detalhe que "muita gente" esquece é que na condição do `for` você pode colocar qualquer coisa (não somente `valor < tamanho`, que apesar de ser o mais comum, não é a única possibilidade). O mesmo vale para as demais partes: eu posso inicializar ambas as variáveis de uma vez, e colocar o decremento da coluna juntamente com o incremento da linha. Ficaria assim:

```
public static int somaDiagonal(int[][] matriz) {
    int soma = 0;
    for (int linha = 0, coluna = matriz[0].length - 1; linha < matriz.length && coluna >= 0; linha++, coluna--) {
        soma += matriz[linha][coluna];
    }
    return soma;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada @hkotsubo, deu certo agora :) .