# JAVA - Como comparar colunas de uma matriz int[][]

Tags: java, array, matriz

Tenho que comparar as linhas e colunas de uma matriz e saber se elas se repetem.

Para comparar as linhas, foi "fácil", mas tô apanhando para comparar as colunas.

Para resolver temporariamente eu estou transpondo a matriz, ou seja transformando as linhas em colunas e colunas em linha,s para poder usar o mesmo raciocinio da comparação de linhas. Eu gostaria de uma solução mais elegante, pois tá parecendo gambiarra.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ValidaLinhasColunas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // MATRIZ PARA TESTE
        // As linhas 0 e 5 sao iguais
        // As colunas 1 e 3 sao iguais
        int[][] matriz = {{0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0}, 
                          {0, 6, 1, 6, 3, 0},
                          {0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 8}, 
                          {1, 7, 0, 7, 0, 1},
                          {0, 5, 0, 5, 1, 0},
                          {0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0}};
            
        // Vai ser passado em parametro para os metodos 
        int linhaParaComparar = 0;
        int colunaParaComparar = 1;

        compararLinhas(matriz, linhaParaComparar);  
        compararColunas(matriz, colunaParaComparar);
    }


    /**
     * Compara a linhas passada como parametro com as demais da matriz
     * 
     * @param matriz
     * @param linhaParaComparar
     */
    public static void compararLinhas(int[][] matriz, int linhaParaComparar) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            // Compara linha passada em parametro com as outras da matriz 
            // (excluindo a passada em paramentro).
            if(Arrays.equals(matriz[linhaParaComparar], matriz[i]) 
                    && matriz[linhaParaComparar] != matriz[i]) {

                System.out.println("A linha " + linhaParaComparar + " é igual à " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compara a coluna passada como parametro com as demais da matriz
     * 
     * MAS ANTES 
     * 
     * Transforma as linhas da matriz passada em parametro em colunas e as
     * colunas em linhas para efetuar a validacao.
     * 
     * @param matriz
     * @param colunaParaComparar
     */
    public static void compararColunas(int[][] matriz, int colunaParaComparar) {

        // Matriz temporaria tera como quantidade de linhas, a quantidade de colunas
        // da matriz passada em parametro. E tera a quantidade de colunas da matriz
        // passada em parametro.

        int[][] matrizTemp = new int[matriz[0].length][matriz.length];

        // Transformando linhas da matriz original em colunas na matriz temporaria
        // e colunas da matriz original em linhas na matriz temporaria
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizTemp.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizTemp.length; j++) {

                matrizTemp[i][j] = matriz[j][i];

                //System.out.print(matrizTemp[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }

        // Mesmo processo do método "compararLinhas". Poderia ter sido chamado
        // aqui, mas por enquanto mantido assim
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizTemp.length; i++) {

            if(Arrays.equals(matrizTemp[colunaParaComparar], matrizTemp[i]) && matrizTemp[colunaParaComparar] != matrizTemp[i]) {

                System.out.println("A coluna " + colunaParaComparar + " é igual à " + i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obs: para o código abaixo, estou assumindo que a matriz está com as dimensões corretas. Digo isso porque na verdade não existem matrizes em Java: o que temos são arrays de arrays (um array no qual cada elemento é outro array), e não há uma forma de obrigar que todos tenham o mesmo tamanho (outras linguagens possuem este recurso, [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145897/112052)). Enfim, estou assumindo que de fato todos os arrays que representam as linhas possuem o mesmo tamanho, então não estou fazendo nenhuma verificação de tamanho.

---

Eu sugiro modificar um pouco o código. Por exemplo, em vez de um método que "faz tudo" para todas as linhas e outro que faz tudo para todas as colunas, faça um método que saiba como comparar apenas 2 linhas:

```
// retorna true se as linhas "lin1" e "lin2" são iguais, false se forem diferentes
public static boolean linhasIguais(int[][] matriz, int lin1, int lin2) {
    return Arrays.equals(matriz[lin1], matriz[lin2]);
}
```

E outro para comparar apenas 2 colunas:

```
// retorna true se as colunas "col1" e "col2" são iguais, false se forem diferentes
public static boolean colunasIguais(int[][] matriz, int col1, int col2) {
    for (int[] linha : matriz) { // para cada linha da matriz, os elementos das colunas col1 e col2 devem ser iguais
        if (linha[col1] != linha[col2]) {
            // achei um elemento diferente, não preciso continuar verificando o resto
            return false;
        }
    }
    // se chegou até aqui, é porque todos são iguais
    return true;
}
```

Para comparar as linhas é simples, pois como cada linha é um array de `int`, basta usar o que já tem pronto.

Para as colunas, não há um método direto, mas não é tão complicado: em cada linha da matriz, o elemento da coluna `i` estará na posição `i` desta linha (ou seja, na posição `i` do array). Então basta percorrer todas as linhas da matriz e ver se os elementos das posições indicadas são iguais.

Se eu encontrar um diferente, posso retornar `false` imediatamente (pois se já encontrei um diferente, nem preciso verificar o resto).

---

Depois, basta usar esses métodos para fazer a busca. No seu caso, você está buscando a partir de uma linha ou coluna específicas, então ficaria:

```
int linhaParaComparar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    if (i != linhaParaComparar && linhasIguais(matriz, i, linhaParaComparar)) {
        System.out.printf("As linhas %d e %d são iguais\n", i, linhaParaComparar);
    }
}

int colunaParaComparar = 1;
// tamanho da primeira linha é a quantidade de colunas
for (int i = 0; i < matriz[0].length; i++) {
    if (i != colunaParaComparar && colunasIguais(matriz, i, colunaParaComparar)) {
        System.out.printf("As colunas %d e %d são iguais\n", i, colunaParaComparar);
    }
}
```

---

Mas se quiser, você pode também procurar por **todas** as linhas e colunas que são iguais. Nesse caso, eu tenho que comparar "todas com todas", então seriam 2 *loops* aninhados:

```
// procurar linhas iguais
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length - 1; i++) { // vai até a penúltima
    for (int j = i + 1; j < matriz.length; j++) { // vai de "i + 1" até a última
        if (linhasIguais(matriz, i, j)) {
            System.out.printf("As linhas %d e %d são iguais\n", i, j);
        }
    }
}

// procurar colunas iguais
for (int i = 0; i < matriz[0].length - 1; i++) { // vai até a penúltima
    for (int j = i + 1; j < matriz[0].length; j++) { // vai de "i + 1" até a última
        if (colunasIguais(matriz, i, j)) {
            System.out.printf("As colunas %d e %d são iguais\n", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

No caso, o primeiro `for` vai da primeira até a penúltima (linha ou coluna, o raciocínio é o mesmo). Depois, o segundo `for` vai de `i + 1` até a última. Assim, eu comparo a primeira com a segunda, terceira, etc, até a última. Depois, comparo a segunda com a terceira, quarta, etc, até a última, e assim por diante.

Desta forma eu encontro todas as linhas e colunas que são iguais.

Comment: Nossa! Ajudou muito! Muito obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Se você abrir mão de usar o método utilitário **Arrays.equals()**, pode implementar o método **compararColunas** comparando os elementos de cada coluna um por um:

```
public static void compararColunas(int[][] matriz, int colunaParaComparar) {


    for (int c = 0; c < matriz.length; c++) {
        if (colunaParaComparar != c) {
            boolean iguais = true;

            for (int l = 0; l < matriz.length; l++) {
                if (matriz[l][colunaParaComparar] != matriz[l][c]) {
                    iguais = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (iguais) {
                System.out.println("A coluna " + colunaParaComparar + " é igual à " + c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show de resposta. Obrigado